# How to turn a direct link file into a .torrent file?

Tags: bittorrent, utorrent, c++, p2p

I want to to know how to make a .torrent file of a **direct link file**, this is similar to **web seed** but i don't have the file in my local pc, i know this can be done because there are websites that actually convert a web link into a torrent file, but i am interested in how to do it manually.

This is not a normal way to create torrents but sometimes i need to create torrents legally using multiple files that are stored in different web addresses then tell the my torrent client to make a folder of them.

I know some people will be searching how to do this, if you know the answers please tell us.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible.
You need to have direct access to the file, to be able to hash the pieces that a file is divided up into when a torrent is created.
Those websites works by first downloading the file and then create the torrent.

Comment: What you said may be right but is there a way to force the torrent client to download the web seeded files without verifying the checksum of divided pieces ? letting the client to verify only the corresponding names and download from the web adresses, i know it's not possible to do it normal way but may be by programming and editing some features to make a torrent client work this way.

Comment: Thank you Encombe for your answers, that's right i was expecting to hear that it is possible, but i'm not the one who downvoted, i have only 6 reputations. please if you heard anything related to my question please let me know.